# Confusion on Linear Equation Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the following problem I understand everything except where $2x_2 = 1 + x_3$ came from, can anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: subtract (2) from (1) and isolate $ x_2$

Comment: I see, thank you that was simple.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following augmented matrix:

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We applied row reduction by doing the following operation: $-R_2+R_1->R_1$ (this isn't shown in the text)

You will get the following:

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The first row can be read as: $2x_2-x_3=1$ which is equal to $2x_2=1+x_3$

Comment: Great, thanks this was simple enough!